# how to open url in new window without appending local url

Tags: javascript, html

```
let url = "www.w3schools.com"

<a href={url} target="_blank">{url}</a>
```

I am trying to open url in the new tab but i am getting `http://localhost:9998/www.w3schools.com` in the new window instead of `https://www.w3schools.com/`

Comment: let finalurl = "http://" + url;

Comment: can i append like this is this right way

Comment: yes, or something like `<a href={'http://' + url} .....`

Answer (score 3):

```
let url = "https://www.w3schools.com"

<a href={url} target="_blank">{url}</a>
```

You need to specify the protocol as well, or the URL will be treated as relative.

Comment: but my url has only www.w3schools.com

Comment: @Nsevens  I had the same issue today and this helped me out! thx!